# How do I completely disable user profiles and the dedicated login page in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, users

I am building a site in which user accounts matter only to provide the `authenticated` / `not authenticated` information. I created a custom login block that is always displayed (in the header of the website). I want to reach the following two points:

- Since user profiles are not needed, I want to disable them for usability reasons. The users should, after login, be redirected to the landing page of my website.
- Also, I want to disable the dedicated login page that appears, i.e., upon entering the wrong password.

Is there any easy way to do these things?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can change built in menu / page callbacks with [`hook_menu_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7)

For example, alter [`user_menu`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_menu/7)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter
 */
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items){
  // Go to front page when visiting /user and /user/login
  $items['user']['page callback'] = 'drupal_goto';
}
```